# Is $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\mathrm{span}\{v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3\}$ if $v_1,v_2,v_3\in V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is $\mathrm{span}\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}=\mathrm{span}\{v_1+v_2,v_1+v_3,v_2+v_3\}$ if $v_1,v_2,v_3 \in V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

I know that this is true if you assume that $V$ is over any field where $2\ne 0$, but what if $2=0$ like in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: Well, I've assumed that the vectors are linearly independent. Otherwise one can reduce the problem to less that three vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, is not! (At least whenever $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent.)

Suppose $v_1=a_1(v_1+v_2)+a_2(v_2+v_3)+a_3(v_3+v_1)$. Then $1=a_1+a_3$, $0=a_1+a_2$, and $0=a_2+a_3$. Summing up we get $1=0$, a contradiction.